# .NET Core for ArmV7 32 bit processor

Tags: c#, mono, .net-core, embedded-linux

My organization is having a firmware for embedded device, written in C# using Mono on a custom linux on an armv7 32 bit processor. Now I want to upgrade it to use .NET Core 2.0 for this and removing the mono layer from it. But on googling I found that .NET Core is supported only on  64-bit linux distributions. So please guide me that whether it is possible to use .NET Core for this or not.

Comment: `.Net Core` Arm32 builds are available as **community supported builds** for `.NET Core` 2.0, and thus are not officially supported via Microsoft (no support life-cycle policy). The `.NET Core` JIT depends on the `armv7` instruction set and there are builds available for hardware platforms such as RPi 2 and RPi 3 running linux that support a Windows/macOS build/compile cycle and runtime deployment to RPi

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover. I looked that and tried to develop a helloworld application using that but it was not working on my target. I think these are specific to RPi. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/build/ states that you can also build .NET core as per your toolchain. I think I should try for this.